# Post data using WebClient in C# and server replay Bad Gateway

Tags: c#, post, webclient

I need to write c# code for Login at myServer.
I try with this code, but myServer reply me always with the same response
**(502) Bad Gateway**

```
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
        string result = "";
        string json = "{\"UserName\": \"myUser\", \"Password\": \"myPassword\"}";

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            result = client.UploadString("https://<myServer>/Login", "POST", json;
        }
```

When I try to connect to server with the Google Chrome App **Postman** or **Arc**, the Login have successful.

Where is the error in my code?

Comment: Without any specification about how the server is working and expecting the data is hard to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For resolve this problem I had used the **HttpWebResponse** class instead of **WebClient**.

This is the finally code

```
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://myserver");
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                UserName = "<myUserName>",
                Password = "<myPassword>"
            });
            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
```